# ftd2xx.dll with Qt and mingw

Tags: qt, usb, mingw, ftdi

I apparently have done something really wrong, and there must be a simple solution.  I've a USB device that I'm trying to talk to that uses a FTDI USB to RS232 converter.  They provide a driver library (ftd2xx.dll) and header file (ftd2xx.h) as a programming interface.  I created a simple project in QtCreator that, to this point does nothing.  It compiles and runs fine.  However, as soon as I include ftd2xx.h, I get a host of errors.  For example:

```
typedef PVOID  FT_HANDLE;
typedef ULONG  FT_STATUS;
typedef void (*PFT_EVENT_HANDLER)(DWORD,DWORD);
WORD VendorId;
```

These lines, and many similar to them, cause these errors:

```
‘PVOID’ does not name a type
‘ULONG’ does not name a type
Typedef ‘PFT_EVENT_HANDLER’ is initialized (use decltype instead)
‘WORD’ does not name a type
```

I'm not sure where to go from here.  I've spoken to FTDI support and they say the only header file I need is ftd2xx.h, which is the one that is causing the issues.  I'm overlooking something here.

Comment: Bryan, since this is not a discussion forum, the "solved" comments are out of place. You should accept an answer that provides the solution, or write your own if none of the answers do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the following:

```
#include <Windows.h> // comes first
#include "ftd2xx.h" // comes *after* Windows.h
```

The FTDI include file is broken as it doesn't properly include the windows header even though it relies on windows types. You must do it yourself instead.

Comment: @BryanGreenway You shouldn't. FTDI should feel really embarrassed, because a) their "support" doesn't know the answer to possibly the most often asked question they get; b) after all these years they still didn't bother to fix their broken header file.